# Abstract classes and Servlets in Java EE

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

What is meant by the abstract class and why is a generic class in the hierarchy of servlets called an abstract class?

Comment: What does J2EE have to do with this? Abstract classes and generics are part of Java SE.

Comment: please clarify your Question.

Answer (score 1):

Read [What is an abstract class, and when should it be used?](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0084.html)